# How can I get the value of the cryptocurrency on a specified date by IMPORTXML?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a google spreadsheet.
I can get a current price of a cryptocurrency GST by

```
IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/ja/currencies/green-satoshi-token/'","//div[contains(@class,'priceValue')]")
```

How can I get the value of the cryptocurrency on a specified date?

Comment: not possible from coinmarketcap unless you use their api

Comment: Instead of scraping a webpage, which is inherently unstable, you'd be better off finding an API that supports this.

Comment: >player0 Thank you. Do you know other platforms where we can get the price on a specified date without using API?

Comment: @Sakurai.JJ Why would you not use an API?

Comment: Thanks. I started to use the API. I'll close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by some community members, getting data ( [historical](https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20130505/) ) by web scraping can be unstable and it is recommended to use a proper service such as the provider's [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) for this.